# how to use FIllChar on packed boolean array?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, if I declare an array of boolean as packed array such as:

```
var
   arr: packed array of boolean;
begin
  SetLength(arr, 100);
  FillChar(arr[0], Length(arr) * SizeOf(arr[0]), True);
end;
```

Is this right?

Comment: A packed boolean array? Is that much like the TBits object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Delphi `packed` has no meaning when used on an array. All array elements are addressable. That is every array element is at least one byte in size. In Delphi it is not possible to pack 8 elements into a single byte as is possible in some other variants of Pascal.

That means that your call to `FillChar` will behave as you intend.

Comment: so i can be sure that in all version of delphi,   SizeOf(boolean) is certain and it is equal to SizeOf(arr[0])?

Comment: Well, `arr[0]` has type `Boolean so yes, `SizeOf(Boolean) = SizeOf(arr[0])`